# Why does my code show an error for a file that is not present in my android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle, build.gradle

I have a problem in android studio.
I imported this project and was trying to use logcat and timber log but it is showing error in build and also in logcat i cannot see my project, no debuggable process is showing.

This is the build.gradle file

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.30'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

This gradle app code

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.dessertpusher"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-alpha4'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.7.1'
}
```

This is the Error, i dont have values.xml resource in my resource tab

```
.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\d8475bbb2e3cd4785bafd0a23122f74a\constraintlayout-2.0.0-alpha4\res\values\values.xml:209:5-3555: AAPT: error: resource attr/motionProgress (aka com.example.android.dessertpusher:attr/motionProgress) not found.
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're hitting the following issue in `constraintlayout:2.0.0-alpha4`: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/136103084

The issue seems to be fixed in `2.0.0-beta3`, so hopefully using a newer version will resolve your problem. According to the [Google's Maven Repository](https://maven.google.com/web/index.html), the latest version of `constraintlayout` is `2.0.0-beta6`.